# passing argumnets as param={} in ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am new to ruby and started learning ruby concepts

From the below code segment i just want to know why passing `params = {}` as arguments
i dont understand assigning `params={}`..what does it meant?

```
def go_to_print_options(params = {})
  if 'short' == params['flow']
    short_flow_to_print_options(params)
  else
    params[:mobile] ? print_options(params) :flow_to_print_options(params)
  end
end
```

also what is this checkinh means       `if 'short' == params['flow']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `params={}` as a method argument denotes that you can send a variable argument hash as an argument, while method call. And if no argument is passed, it is treated as an Empty hash, *by default*.

So, for the above method, you can call `go_to_print_options(flow: 'short', mobile: 'apple')`.
You may wonder that this is not a `hash`; but there's the catch - if `Hash` is the last argument in function call, you can skip the *curly braces*.

So effectively, for your method:
`go_to_print_options(flow: 'short', mobile: 'apple')` and `go_to_print_options({flow: 'short', mobile: 'apple'})` are same.
And in the function defintion, `{flow: 'short', mobile: 'apple'}` is mapped to `params`.

```
params[:flow] #=> 'short'
params[:mobile] #=> 'apple'
params[:foo] #=> nil #since no such key is present
```

Notice that those are symbols above, you can pass the strings as keys too as: `go_to_print_options("flow" => 'short', "mobile" => 'apple')`

If you just call `go_to_print_options`. It will still be valid, and `params` will be an empty hash (`{}`) with absolutely no keys, whatsoever.

By passing `Hash` as an argument, you can send variable number of arguments to your method. And in the method definition, you can just access them as `params['flow']`, which will give the value as `short` for above call.

`if 'short' == params['flow']` is a simple conditional in Ruby. You are checking the value of `params['flow']` and `short` for equality. If `params['flow']` is indeed `short`, the underlying block will be called (`short_flow_to_print_options(params)`)

Comment: `params={}` actually just means that the method takes a single argument whose default value is an empty Hash. Saying `go_to_print_options(6)` would still be a valid method call even though it would fall over with a TypeError at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know. I should add this in answer too. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`params` is an optional argument to the method `go_to_print_options`. If it is not given when the method is called the default value (here, `{}`, as empty `Hash`) is used.

`params['flow']` gets the value of the `'flow'` key of the hash `params` (or `nil`, if `params` has no such key.